# Java Android development: Is it bad practice to reference other classes static Strings get Intent parameters?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Supposed I want to pass a String with an intent.  Is it bad OOP practice to go:

```
public class MessageSender extends Activity
{
    public static final THE_STRING = "my message";
    ...
        String value = "This is what I need to send";
        Intent displayResultsIntent = new Intent(this, MessageReceiver.class);
        displayResultsIntent.putExtra(MessageSender.THE_STRING, value);
    ...
}

public class MessageReceiver extends Activity
{
    ...
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String yourMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MessageSender.THE_STRING);
    ...
}
```

My instinct says there should be a better way.  It seems if I'm using the static variable of another class in MessageReciever I could just as well make

```
"This is what I want to send"
```

static and reference that directly in MessageReceiver.

I could specify in comments for the method that creates the intent that the String parameter will be "my message".  But that seems more error prone if you update the name of the parameter without updating comments.

I've read you should try to avoid tying classes together by using each others variables.  Do we just have to cheat somewhat when using intents?

Comment: Its the value specific to the sender or to the message type?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html Read this, hope it will help you also. It says to avoid unnecessary objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `MessageSender.THE_STRING` directly(because of static) in any class in your app, because after build APK its directly assign to that method or variable.

your code example

```
public static final THE_STRING = "my message";
Intent displayResultsIntent = new Intent(this, MessageReceiver.class);
displayResultsIntent.putExtra(MessageSender.THE_STRING, value);
```

after build APK above code converted to

```
Intent displayResultsIntent = new Intent(this, MessageReceiver.class);
displayResultsIntent.putExtra("my message", value);
```

and

```
String yourMessage = intent.getStringExtra("my message");
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've read you should try to avoid tying classes together by using each
>   others variables. Do we just have to cheat somewhat when using
>   intents?

What you declared is a constant. With `final` you declare that its value can't change, and with `static` the it is not linked to the specific instance, but it is created just once. In the use case you described it is indeed a good practice. You are not either cheating nor tying classes together.